# Get date from SQL Server audit filename

Tags: sql-server, audit, type-conversion

SQL Server audit filenames use the following pattern:

Name_GUID_PartitionNumber_Timestamp.sqlaudit

An example filename below:

Audit-ObjectChanges_2D94C1E8-CCAD-405F-A9F2-A45FA5EDAD8F_0_132327053636850000.sqlaudit

If I query `sys.dm_server_audit_status` I see the `status_time` column has a value of 2020-04-30 08:29:22.6070000 for four audits I have. All filenames have 132327053636850000 in the timestamp part of the filename.

So I assume 132327053636850000 = 2020-04-30 08:29:22.6070000, but how can I convert the filename timestamp into datetime format for previous audit files?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like number of 100 nanosecond ticks since `1601-01-01` ([`FILETIME`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090306-00/?p=18913))

So based on that the following works (`125911584000000000` is the number of these ticks between 1601 and 2000. This is subtracted first to avoid overflowing an `int`)

It also looks like the time returned is UTC so you will need to convert to your local time zone (which I have made an assumption about).

```
DECLARE @value    BIGINT = 132327053636850000,
        @datetime DATETIME2

SELECT @datetime = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 
                           @value%10000000 / 10000, 
                             DATEADD(SECOND, 
                             ( @value - 125911584000000000 ) / 10000000, 
                             CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATETIME2)))

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), 
                 SWITCHOFFSET(@datetime,
                 DATEPART(TZOFFSET, @datetime AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time')))
```

Returns

```
2020-04-30 08:29:23.685
```

Comment: Perfect. I've checked with previous files and really happy with this. Thank you.